# Changing the background color from blockquote to blockquote in rmarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

Take the following `rmarkdown` file. I would like to have each `blockquote` rendered with a different background color (yellow the first one and white the second one), but the second `css` chunk seems to neutralize the first one.

Could someone please help me?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


```{css echo = FALSE}
blockquote{
background-color: rgb(255,255,153);
}
```

> this is a note 1
>
> the is is still the note


```{css echo = FALSE}
blockquote{
background-color: initial;
}
```

> this is a note 2
>
> the is is still the note
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<div style="background-color:rgba(250, 230, 7, 1);">

> this is a note 1
>
> the is is still the note

</div>


<div style="background-color:rgba(63, 237, 40, 1);">

> this is a note 2
>
> the is is still the note

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @manro! Your solution works! But do you any idea why my approach does not work?

Comment: @PaulSmith yes, I know. I add now an explain.

Comment: Thanks, @manro!

Comment: @PaulSmith By my unprofessional opinion, you should style every single ```blockquote``` by ```#```. F.e. : ```<style> blockquote {...something} #bl1 {...something} ... #blN{...something} </style>```

Comment: @PaulSmith Good luck in the future work, now I can going to sleep. Bye bye ;)